# Why aria2c Linux version is much larger than Windows version

Tags: linux, gcc, aria2

Currently, I start using [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) in Linux. At the beginning, I thought I just need to download a executable file just like 'aria2c.exe' in Windows. But I was wrong. In Linux, I need to use c++ compiler to compile and run 'make' command. It takes few minutes to finish.

When it finished, executable file 'aria2c' is 69MB which much larger than 'aria2c.exe'(4MB).

```
// linux
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 69M Aug 29 00:02 aria2c

// windows
aria2c.exe   4.66MB
```

I was wondering what cause the difference.

Comment: My guess is that you build with debug information. Try to [`strip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) the program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It works! Just 2.5MB left. Thanks a lot! But I have another question: why not compiles by user instead of publishing executable file like Windows to download?

Comment: aria2c is often packaged by distributions, which thus provide the binary

Comment: @A.B Thanks a lot and I found this [Binary vs. Source Packages](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/binary-source-packages-use/)